# Why do softwares often keep local data in $HOME/.<appname>?

Tags: linux, local-storage, home-folder

Most application I usually install (opam, cargo, vscode, julia, ...) keep a local storage in my home folder. 
Is there a reason for this preference? Or better, are there downsides to the alternatives?

For example sometimes it is suggested that such files should be located on /var, or in ~/.local/share, but there might be issues or annoyances in using these folder in "cross-distro" application.

Do you know any such possible issues?

[any answer o any of the three questions i asked here would be satisfactory]

Comment: I selected the appdata tag by mistake; this question has nothing to do with that %appdata% but i don't know how to remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Google+ post by Rob Pike,
[A lesson in shortcuts](https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp),
is given this explanation :

> Long ago, as the design of the Unix file system was being worked out, the entries `.` and `..` appeared, to make navigation easier. I'm not sure but I believe `..` went in during the Version 2 rewrite, when the file system became hierarchical (it had a very different structure early on).  When one typed `ls`, however, these files appeared, so either Ken or Dennis added a simple test to the program. It was in assembler then, but the code in question was equivalent to something like this:
>
> ```
>     if (name[0] == '.') continue;
> ```
>
> This statement was a little shorter than what it should have been, which is
>
> ```
>     if (strcmp(name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(name, "..") == 0) continue;
> ```
>
> but hey, it was easy.
>
> Two things resulted.
>
> First, a bad precedent was set. A lot of other lazy programmers
>   introduced bugs by making the same simplification. Actual files
>   beginning with periods are often skipped when they should be counted.
>
> Second, and much worse, the idea of a "hidden" or "dot" file was
>   created. As a consequence, more lazy programmers started dropping
>   files into everyone's home directory. I don't have all that much stuff
>   installed on the machine I'm using to type this, but my home directory
>   has about a hundred dot files and I don't even know what most of them
>   are or whether they're still needed. Every file name evaluation that
>   goes through my home directory is slowed down by this accumulated
>   sludge.
>
> I'm pretty sure the concept of a hidden file was an unintended
>   consequence. It was certainly a mistake.
>
> (For those who object that dot files serve a purpose, I don't dispute that but counter that it's the files that serve the purpose, not the convention for their names. They could just as easily be in $HOME/cfg or $HOME/lib, which is what we did in Plan 9, which had no dot files. Lessons can be learned.)

So what I understand is that :

As these "dot files" became invisible, other programmers jumped in
and decided that the place to store their precious configuration data
was in dot files right along with the `.` and `..` files.
As in the beginning file hierarchy was not very evolved,
they all ended up in the $HOME directory, and pretty quick this became
an unwritten convention to which everybody conformed,
following in the steps of the founding fathers.

This gave rise to such monstrosities as :

[image]

Reference :

[Linux History: How Dot Files Became Hidden Files](https://linux-audit.com/linux-history-how-dot-files-became-hidden-files/)